# getting country information for authenticated user in twitter api

Tags: php, json, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using Abraham library ...

I'm trying to pull information about user and show it ..

I'm trying to get Country information for authenticated user ..

I tried **account/settings** , **users/show** and **account/verify_credentials**

but they all didn't give me Country information for the user ..

Comment: Making a request to users/show should return a json response, including the users location: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show...

Comment: this just shows the location .. I want the Country and the Country code in profile settings .. thnx anyway